# Jenkins Fargate Plugin cant acceess Nexus in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, aws-fargate, nexus3

I am using Jenkins Fargate Plugin(https://plugins.jenkins.io/amazon-ecs/) for builds and push. I have an EC2 machine and in this machine I have Jenkins master, nexus repository and sonarqube. And with this jenkins fargate plugin I create fargate containers for jenkins workers. And this workers in same subnet in EC2 machine and same vpc. But when I use whistlist on 443 port for nexus and sonarqube created fargate container cant access to nexus and sonarqube but they are on same public subnet. What should I do for the connection. I use different security groups for EC2 machine and fargate conrtainers but subnets and vpc is same.

I need to close jenkins master nexus and sonarqube login pages so ı need to use whistlist right other way can close? what should I do for comminication fargate container and EC2 machine?

Update:
Subnet is public subnet.
Security group for fargate outbound rules is all open.
The error is "Connection time out".

Comment: need more details, what is the error message thrown in fargate? what is the outbound rules in fargate container security group? fargate container subnet has routing to internet?

Comment: @karthikeayan Thank you for respond. There is no error message. Connection going timed out. Outbound rules is all protocols all port is open. And subnet is public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was while resolving the domain, we were experiencing connection timeouts because it was being resolved over the public IP. However, we resolved the issue within the Jenkins pipeline by editing the /etc/hosts file to enable resolution using the private IP. This solved the problem.